# Surface View not redrawing rect correctly

Tags: android, view, surfaceview

I am trying to have a rect wander over the screen from left to right. In the MyPaddle class the X coordinate is incremented in every loop. In the SurfaceView I am trying to draw the rects, so it appears that they are wandering over the screen. My code:

```
    public GameView(Context context) {

    super(context);

    gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);
    sc = (StartingClass) context;

    holder = getHolder();

    holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

           @Override

           public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                  boolean retry = true;
                  gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);

                  while (retry) {
                         try {
                              gameLoopThread.join();
                               retry = false;
                         } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                  }
           }

           @Override

           public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                  gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
                  gameLoopThread.start();
           }

           @Override

           public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,

                         int width, int height) {

           }

    });

  }

@Override

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

      PongPaddle myPaddle = sc.getMyPaddle();
      PongPaddle compPaddle = sc.getCompPaddle();

      paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      paint.setStrokeWidth(0);


      canvas.drawRect(Math.round(myPaddle.getCenterX()-sc.getPaddleWidth()/2), getHeight() -30, Math.round(myPaddle.getCenterX()+sc.getPaddleWidth()/2), getHeight(), paint);
      canvas.drawRect(Math.round(compPaddle.getCenterX()-sc.getPaddleWidth()/2),0, Math.round(compPaddle.getCenterX()+sc.getPaddleWidth()/2), 30, paint);
     // super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

The rects are drawn but it seems the screen is not reset, but the rects are drawn on top of eachother. The result is that the rect grows to the right, creating a line after covering the screen. Any ideas? Thanks for any effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a couple of problems with your code:

1. Android does not clear the screen for you.  You need to start each drawing session by erasing the screen, or you will see previously-rendered content.  This is why you're getting a line smearing across the screen.  Also, the output surface may be double- or triple-buffered, so in some cases it will actually "flicker" as you animate if you don't erase it.
2. You're not drawing on the Surface.  SurfaceView has two parts, the Surface and the View.  By overriding `onDraw()` you're drawing on the View, just as you would for a [custom view](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html), except that by using SurfaceView you're wasting system resources.  If you want to draw on the Surface, you need to get the Canvas from the SurfaceHolder.  (If drawing on the View works, go with that though so you can take advantage of hardware acceleration.)

See also the [Surface lifecycle](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity) section of the graphics architecture doc.

Comment: How can I erase the screen? I am calling:  try { c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas(); synchronized (view.getHolder()) {view.onDraw(c); }  from the GameThread, so I am getting the Canvas from the SurfaceHolder. Adding  canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK); before drawing the rects solved the problem with the smearing. Is this correct?

Comment: `View#onDraw()` is called by the View hierarchy.  If you intend to call it yourself, give it a different name, and leave `onDraw()` with its default do-nothing implementation.  `Canvas#drawColor()` is a fine way to clear the Canvas.